# How to show/hide radio buttons by clicking a button?

Tags: graphics, list-manipulation, button

I'm implementing a neural network for school and I have a function where the user can interact with the variables. 
The thing is, I have a lot of variables and I want partially hide show them using buttons so that I can split them in two groups.

How can I achieve this?

Here is what I wrote so far (and more variables will arrive):

```
loc = GeoPosition[Entity["City", {"Zurich", "Zurich", "Switzerland"}]];
date = DateObject[{2020, 06, 1, #}] & /@ Range@24;
activitiesDay = {4, 2, 12, 2, 1} -> {"none", "germination", 
    "growing", "flower_formetion", "fructification"};
activitiesNight = {4, 2, 12, 2, 1} -> {"none", "germination", 
    "growing", "flower_formetion", "fructification"};
ventiletionflapsPositionsDay = {3, 1} -> {"closed", "open"};
ventiletionflapsPositionsNight = {12, 1} -> {"closed", "open"};
shadesheetPositionsDay = {3, 2, 1} -> {"closed", "shaded", "open"};
shadesheetPositionsNight = {1, 3, 3} -> {"closed", "shaded", "open"};
DayQ[hour_] := 7 < hour < 18
```

```
GenerateRoomEvent[] := Module[{hour, day},
  $actEvent = Dataset@<| 
     "hour" -> (hour = RandomInteger@24),
     "day" -> (day = 
        DayName[date = 
          DateObject[{RandomInteger[{2000, 2020}], RandomInteger@12, 
            RandomInteger[{1, 27}], hour}]]),
     
     (*Parameters outside*)
     
     "temperatureOutside" -> Normal[WeatherData[loc, "Temperature", date]][[1, 2, 1]],
     "airhumidityOutside" -> Normal [WeatherData[loc, "Humidity", date]][[1, 2]],
     "windspeedOutside" -> Normal[WeatherData[loc, "WindSpeed", date]][[1, 2, 1]],
     "winddirectionOutside" -> Normal[WeatherData[loc, "WindDirection", date]][[1, 2, 1]],
     "sunPosition" -> Flatten@{SunPosition[loc, date ][[All, 1]]},
     "cloudsCoverage" -> Round[RandomReal[], .1],
     "CO2ConcentretionOutside" -> 10000*Round[RandomReal[], 0.001],
     
     (*condition Day-/NightQ Air outside*)
     If[DayQ@hour, {
       "activity" -> RandomChoice[activitiesDay , 1],
       "ventiletionflapsPositions" -> RandomChoice[ventiletionflapsPositionsDay, 2],
        "shadesheetPosition" -> RandomChoice[shadesheetPositionsDay, 2]
       },
      {
       "activity" -> RandomChoice[activitiesNight , 1],
       "ventiletionflapsPositions" -> RandomChoice[ventiletionflapsPositionsNight, 2],
        "shadesheetPosition" -> RandomChoice[shadesheetPositionsNight, 2]}
      ],
     
     (*Parameters Air Inside*)
     
     "temperatureInside" -> Round@RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[21, 5]],
     "brightnessInside" -> RandomChoice[{0, 100, 200, 300, 400}],
     "ventilationInside" -> RandomChoice[{0, .2, .5, 1.0}],
     "airhumidityInside" -> Round[RandomReal[], 0.1],
     "CO2concentretionInside" -> 10000*Round[RandomReal[], 0.001],
     
     (*Parameters Soil Inside*)
     
     "wateramountSoil" -> Round[RandomReal[], 0.1],
     "salinitySoil" -> 16*Round[RandomReal[], 0.1],
     "PHValue" -> 14* Round[RandomReal[],0.1]
     |> ]
```

This is the function I wan to change:

```
AddEvent := FormFunction[FormObject[{

     (*Air control*)
     
     "light1" -> <|"Interpreter" -> {"o" -> 2, "-" -> 1, "+" -> 3}, "Control" -> RadioButtonBar|>,
     "light2" -> <|"Interpreter" -> {"o" -> 2, "-" -> 1, "+" -> 3},"Control" -> RadioButtonBar|>,
     "light3" -> <|"Interpreter" -> {"o" -> 2, "-" -> 1, "+" -> 3},"Control" -> RadioButtonBar|>,
     "shadesheet1" -> <|"Interpreter" -> {"o" -> 2, "-" -> 1, "+" -> 3},"Control" -> RadioButtonBar|>,
     "shadesheet2" -> <|"Interpreter" -> {"o" -> 2, "-" -> 1, "+" -> 3},"Control" -> RadioButtonBar|>,
     "heat" -> <|"Interpreter" -> {"o" -> 2, "-" -> 1, "+" -> 3},"Control" -> RadioButtonBar|>,
     "vent" -> <|"Interpreter" -> {"o" -> 2, "-" -> 1, "+" -> 3},"Control" -> RadioButtonBar|>,
     
     (*Soil control*)
     
     "sprinkler1" -> <|"Interpreter" -> {"o" -> 2, "-" -> 1, "+" -> 3}, "Control" -> RadioButtonBar|>,
     "sprinkler2" -> <|"Interpreter" -> {"o" -> 2, "-" -> 1, "+" -> 3},"Control" -> RadioButtonBar|>,
     "sprinkler3" -> <|"Interpreter" -> {"o" -> 2, "-" -> 1, "+" -> 3},"Control" -> RadioButtonBar|>,
     "sprinkler4" -> <|"Interpreter" -> {"o" -> 2, "-" -> 1, "+" -> 3}, "Control" -> RadioButtonBar|>,
     "PH" -> <|"Interpreter" -> {"o" -> 2, "-" -> 1, "+" -> 3}, "Control" -> RadioButtonBar|>,
     "salinity" -> <|"Interpreter" -> {"o" -> 2, "-" -> 1, "+" -> 3},"Control" -> RadioButtonBar|>},
    
    
    AppearanceRules -> <|
      "Title" -> $actEvent,
  "Description" -> "adjust light, sight and climate"|>
], ($eventList = Append[$eventList, Normal@$actEvent -> #]) &][]
```

The tables witch I receive back are a mess: Is there a way to make subtitles and group the objects? (For example group *outside*, *Air* and *Soil*?)

When I run

```
$eventList = {};
GenerateRoomEvent[];
AddEvent;
```

I receive a list of clickable radio buttons and I wanted to create three bigger ones (for example named *outside*, *Air* and *Soil*) above and, by clicking them, show only some of the radio buttons.

How can I do it?

Awaiting a reply, I thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: I recommend that you provide the simplest code that illustrates your problem.